# Preventing divs with images from wrapping oddly in LIs

Tags: html, css

How may I prevent this odd cascading effect when using LI content such as the following: 
http://jsfiddle.net/arPzt/1/

I can achieve the desired behavior by inserting BRs after each LI, but a) the vertical spacing between LIs seem to vary depending on the length of the content and b) there must be some better / more proper way of achieving this.

```
<ul>
<li>
  <div style="background-color: #990000; width:70px; float: left">
      <img style="width: 45px" src="http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/doodles/2013/1-5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #00FF00; margin-left: 70px;" >
  body some interesting large amount of content. some interesting large amount of content.
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div style="background-color: #990000; width:70px; float: left">
      <img style="width: 45px" src="http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/doodles/2013/1-5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #00FF00; margin-left: 70px;" >
  body some interesting large amount of content. some interesting large amount of content.
  </div>    
</li>
<li>
  <div style="background-color: #990000; width:70px; float: left">
      <img style="width: 45px" src="http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/doodles/2013/1-5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #00FF00; margin-left: 70px;" >
  body some interesting large amount of content. some interesting large amount of content.
  </div>    
</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that as an alternative to the `clear:left` suggestions, you consider using `overflow:hidden` on the li elements instead.

While `clear:left` fixes this simple example, you could still have layout issues with any additional content following the list. Using `overflow:hidden` on the li elements will restrict any floating effects to just those items.

More information in [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're floating the elements, but if you want them to clear the previous line, you need to use `clear: left` or `clear: both` if you ever use right floated elements.

```
li {
  clear: left;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arPzt/3/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need to do is simply clear the 'float' after each LI

Like this:

```
<li style="clear:both;">
```